# Refresh NavigationView menu after change locale

Tags: android, locale, navigationview

I'm changing locale programmatically from fragment and everything ok. There is one exception, the NavigationView menu, where language didn't  changing. How to refresh it without recreate all activity.

Mainactivity code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context = this;


    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.setEnabled(false);

    DrawerLayout mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
}
```

R.layout.activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

            <include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

fragment code after choose locale

```
LocaleHelper.setLocale(getActivity(), getResources().getStringArray(R.array.locale)[locale]);

FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(this).attach(this).commit();
```

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_contacts" android:icon="@drawable/ic_people_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/contacts" android:checked="true"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_invoices" android:icon="@drawable/ic_swap_horiz_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/invoices" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_payments" android:icon="@drawable/ic_payment_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/payments" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_history" android:icon="@drawable/ic_receipt_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/history" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_settings" android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/settings" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_info"
                android:title="@string/info" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"/>
</group>
```

Thanx

Comment: How you are populating your nav drawer? list or simple view items.

Comment: items from menu layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've decided this problem

```
private void refreshNavigationView(){

    getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

}
```

That's enought for refresh NavigationView after change locale

But I lose onNavigationItemSelected

As a result at Mainactivity

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the locale has changed
    if (!currentLocale.equals(newConfig.locale)) {
        currentLocale = newConfig.locale;

        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)  this.findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(MainActivity.this);
    }
}
```

At fragment

```
getActivity().onConfigurationChanged(getActivity().getResources().getConfiguration());
```

Answer (score 1):

latest solution in kotlin:

upgrade your appcompat version to `1.6.0` or later

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0'
```

create a function

```
fun setLocale(language: String?) {
    val appLocale: LocaleListCompat = LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags(language)
    AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(appLocale)
}
```

then use it like

```
setLocale("en-EN")
```

it will update and refresh all language change/locale including  **NavigationView**

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code. I haven't tested it but I hope it will work.

```
for (int i = 0, count = navigationView.getChildCount(); i < count; i++) {
    final View child = navigationView.getChildAt(i);
    if (child != null && child instanceof ListView) {
        final ListView menuView = (ListView) child;
        final HeaderViewListAdapter adapter = (HeaderViewListAdapter) menuView.getAdapter();
        final BaseAdapter wrapped = (BaseAdapter) adapter.getWrappedAdapter();
        wrapped.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: wrapped.getCount() return 6 it'l true, i heve 6 items at menu, but notifyDataSetChanged() not refresh menu or not understand new locale

Comment: I've done this: (navigationView.getMenu()).addSubMenu("xxx");  It aded new item, but did't changed locale

Comment: At what point you are calling it onAtttachWindow ? or just after changing locale?

Comment: I put static method in MainActivity and call it from fragmrnt just after change locale  ft.detach(this).attach(this).commit();

                        MainActivity.refreshNavigationView(); I think it shoud be necessary to refresh setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); for reread data and new id from resources

Comment: Ideally should not be. Because drawer is always there it is just hidden due to LEFT gravity. You can try refreshing your NavigationView in the callback onDarwerOpen()

Comment: Please show your menu.xml also , how you are creating menu items.