# Android: Drawer items doesnt change title when language is changed

Tags: android, android-studio

I implemented some string resources for english and romanian. Switching the locale works fine for text fields, but the titles for the drawer items doesnt change when language is changed.

I have the following configuration:

Setting the locale to "ro" in MainActivity

```
    private fun setDefaultLocale(lang: String) {
        val config = android.content.res.Configuration(resources.configuration)
        val locale = Locale(lang)
        Locale.setDefault(locale)
        config.setLocale(locale)
        config.setLayoutDirection(locale)

        resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.displayMetrics)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
        setDefaultLocale("ro")
..... 
}
```

Menu resources:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24"
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:title="@string/menu_home" />

    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_wallpaper_24"
        android:id="@+id/news"
        android:title="@string/menu_news" />

    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_jungle"
        android:id="@+id/jungleTimer"
        android:title="@string/menu_timer" />

    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_damage"
        android:id="@+id/builds"
        android:title="@string/menu_builds" />

    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_settings_24"
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings" />

    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_info_24"
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:title="@string/menu_about" />

    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_feedback"
        android:id="@+id/feedback"
        android:title="@string/menu_feedback" />

    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite"
        android:id="@+id/rateapp"
        android:title="@string/menu_rate" />
</group>
```

Default string xml file:

```
/* Menu translations */
<string name="menu_home">Home</string>
<string name="menu_news">News</string>
<string name="menu_timer">Jungle Timers</string>
<string name="menu_builds">Guides</string>
<string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="menu_about">About</string>
<string name="menu_feedback">Feedback</string>
<string name="menu_rate">Rate the app</string>
```

Romanian strings xml file

```
/* Menu translations */
<string name="menu_home">Acasă</string>
<string name="menu_news">Noutăți</string>
<string name="menu_timer">Cronometru Junglă</string>
<string name="menu_builds">Ghid Campioni</string>
<string name="menu_settings">Setări</string>
<string name="menu_about">Despre</string>
<string name="menu_feedback">Feedback</string>
<string name="menu_rate">Dă-ne o notă</string>
```

Comment: Does the same happens when you change your language in system settings?

Comment: Changing the device language does change the drawer language :D

Comment: If so, I think thats the issue with Activity not restarting when you change it programmatically.

Comment: I've posted this as an answer - please accept it if it's indeed useful

Comment: for latest app locale change solution, you can check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75388129/7728628

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating configuration will not restart your activity, so `Drawer` will not know that you changed locale on the device thus not changing the texts.
If you change your language in system settings it should work.

I propose recreating the activity after you change your configuration programmatically, for example with `activity?.recreate()` method